# Capture Only HTTP traffic in tshark

Tags: http, wireshark

I am new to tshark tool usage. I am trying to use tshark tool for capturing only HTTP traffic but i am unable to do it. Here is the cmd i run to get the all traffic:

```
tshark -c 1000 -w packetFile.pcap
```

Anyway i can filter out only http traffic?

Comment: If UI is ok with you, try WireShark. You can directly select filters in the UI. I think but not sure, it gives you the command line to fire the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a display filter:

```
tshark -Y http
```

If you need to save the capture, you can run the display filter on the output:

```
tshark -r packetFile.pcap -Y http -w packetFile-http.pcap
```

Comment: Display filter is nice, but for capturing only http, this can be used: `tshark -f 'port http'`